# Is it possible to use venvs (virtual environments) with incron?

Tags: python, python-venv

I can't see anything anywhere showing examples of how to use virtual environments with incron http://inotify.aiken.cz/

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Update: 
I run incrontab -e
I then add this line:

```
/home/vmail/jobstat.us/submit/new/ IN_CREATE /home/vmail/jobstatuspy3/bin/python3 /home/vmail/mailtounicodetoarchive.py --context=prd
```

However when I try to run the same from the command line i.e.

```
/home/vmail/jobstatuspy3/bin/python3 /home/vmail/mailtounicodetoarchive.py --context=prd
```

It says

```
vmail@mail:~$ /home/vmail/jobstatuspy3/bin/python3 /home/vmail/mailtounicodetoarchive.py --context=prd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vmail/mailtounicodetoarchive.py", line 14, in <module>
    me = singleton.SingleInstance()
NameError: name 'singleton' is not defined
```

Obviously the above error is because it's not actually executing the command in a venv and so the tendo module which I installed in the venv does not work.

Any thoughts on how to get venvs to work with incron?

Comment: Define *how to use virtual environments with incron* please. Otherwise a valid answer is to install [`pyinotify`](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) using python3.3 `venv` module or `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 1):

Write a shell script with all the commands you would normally use to activate the virtual environment and run your program.

Then setup incron to run the shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `activate` you normally type in your shell directly into your python code. If your project is named `A` it's something like this:

```
activate_this = 'A/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided after investigating further not to use inotify.  An easier approach was to just poll the target directories for files and run my script under supervisor.